# Evaluation of infinite square roots

Tags: square-numbers

The question is:

> Evaluate in simplest form:$\sqrt {2013+2012 \sqrt {2013+2012 \sqrt {2013+2012 \sqrt {...} } } }$

Supposing let "x" be $\sqrt {2013+2012 \sqrt {2013+2012 \sqrt {2013+2012 \sqrt {...} } } }$

Then $x^2=2013+2012 \sqrt {2013+2012 \sqrt {2013+2012 \sqrt {...} } }$

Noticing the "x" still repeats in the equation of $x^2$,

I can conclude $x^2=2013+2012x$

Where solving this equation,

$x^2-2012x-2013=0$

$(x+1)(x-2013)=0$

$(x+1)=0 OR (x-2013)=0$

$x=-1 (Rejected) OR x=2013$

So $\sqrt {2013+2012 \sqrt {2013+2012 \sqrt {2013+2012 \sqrt {...} } } }=2013$

But the problem with this answer is that,it is a whole number.The answer can't go to a whole number of this is an infinite series of square roots where $\sqrt {x}$ is unequal to a whole number.

Basically saying as long as $\sqrt {2013+2012}$ is not a whole number,then the infinite square root **CANNOT** be a whole number.

But the problem is,if the answer is not the whole number?How do I solve this?I don't see any other way according to my 13 year old brain!(Solution that are high and difficult are welcomed and wanted!)

Comment: The problem is that you don't want $\sqrt{2013+2012}$ to be an integer, but $\sqrt{2013+2012x}=\sqrt{2013+2012\cdot 2013}=\sqrt{2013^2}=2013$, which indeed is.

Comment: @dclark but you cannot subsitute "x" that way,because I first stated "x" as that series of square roots,not a simple value of 2013.Before I even solve "x",I cannot say that "x"=2013 that way.Looks like I'm just confused about what I am talking now

Comment: @dclark ahh now I remember what I had to say.But the thing is,infinite square root can only get closer to an integer eventually,but cannot reach the integer.No matter how much I square root,even for 1 billion times,I still cannot get an integer.But yet my answer is a integer?

Comment: Indeed you may, and you've addressed this in your post when you say "the $x$ still repeats". What about this? $$x=\sqrt {2013+2012 \left(\sqrt {2013+2012 \sqrt {2013+2012 \sqrt {...} }}\right)  }=\sqrt{2013+2012 x}$$

Comment: @dclark seems satisfying enough.Thanks

Comment: To your last post, you're touching on more delicate subjects of convergence. If you were to calculate this number you'd have to stop adding more square roots at some point and then you're right, you wouldn't have $2013$, but something close to it. The idea is _in the limit_ these values get arbitrarily close to $2013$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say that:
$$\sqrt {2013+2012 \sqrt {2013+2012 \sqrt {2013+2012 \sqrt {\cdots} } } }=2013$$

It's just like saying that:
$$a_n=\underbrace{\sqrt {2013+2012 \sqrt {\cdots \cdots \sqrt {2013+\sqrt {2012}}} } }_{ n \text{ times }} \\
\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=2013
$$

Now your conclusion is not correct for instance we have :
  $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt 2(\frac{1}{2})^n=0$$

But $\sqrt 2(\frac{1}{2})^n$ is never an integer ,

**To see this in your terms** I will ask you what is the value of :
$$\sqrt 2 (\frac{1}{2})\cdot(\frac{1}{2})\cdot(\frac{1}{2})\cdot (\frac{1}{2})\cdots\cdots \cdots \tag 1$$ you will say that if $x$ is it's value than $x=\frac{1}{2}\cdot x$ and hence $x=0$, but $x=0$ is an integer and the numbers in $(1)$ are never integers! I have to say that this happens whole time and there is no way of finding out if the limit is an integer just looking to the sequence if it's takes integer or rational values.

Comment: well explained.I cannot argue more.